# Datomic can't find Clojure.main

Tags: clojure, datomic

I've been learning Clojure for around a month now and I've decided to experiment with Datomic. I'm following the tutorial on the site exactly, but I can't even get past the first tutorial page (http://docs.datomic.com/first-db.html) because I get the following error on run:

run -m datomic.peer-server -p 8998 -a myaccesskey,mysecret -d firstdb,datomic:mem://firstdb

The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main

I think this is just a classpath issue (I only picked up Java to work with Clojure), but looking at run.bat I think Datomic is set up to determine classpaths automatically, and I'd rather understand why it doesn't work out of the box (presumably a config issue on my machine, although I've tried another).

I've tried the latest version (0.9.5544) as well as the version explicitly mentioned in the tutorial (0.9.5530), as well as installing via Maven. Tried numerous other tutorials and forum-searches as well - plenty of general classpath advice, but nothing relevant to this. Please, send help!

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Update - I seem to have resolved my issue. The instructions on the Datomic tutorial page appear to be incorrect (they say bin/run, but bin\run works). I worked around the bin/run error by running directly from the bin folder, but this obviously had the knock-on effect of making any relative paths incorrect.

I suspect I'm not great at Stack Exchange since I seem to have answered all of my own questions so far, but I hope someone else finds this useful!

Comment: Are you on Windows? That would explains why you need backslashes instead of forward slashes (http://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes)

Comment: I am - the tutorial doesn't specify an OS, but the download included batch files so I probably just assumed. Thanks for the explanation though - I'll have to keep an eye out for this in the rest of the tutorial!